# How do I get the image data on specific objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

In a canvas I created a 2d context. In that context... with a function... I'm able to create some 'circle objects'. Now, what I want, is to get the ImageData of a single circle object instead of the image data of the whole context.

In the code below, you can see my wish commented out.

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var circle = function (X,Y) {
    var that = this;
    that.X = X;
    that.Y = Y;
    that.clicked = function(e) {
        //
        //
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // Code below works fine, on context level
        imgData = ctx.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1);
        //
        // Code below is at the level of the circle, that's what I want, but isn't working
        imgData = that.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1);
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //
        //
        alert(imgData.data[3]);
    }
    that.draw = function () {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(that.X, that.Y);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#33cc33';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
var circles = new Array();
circles.push(new circle(50,50));
document.addEventListener('click',function() {
    circles.forEach(function(circ,index){
        circ.clicked();
    });
})
```

So, how do I get the image data on specific objects?

**edit:**
I understand that I need to draw the circle first, I do that later in my code, but what if I've got a background rect in the context, when I click next to the circle, it will get the imageData of the background rect, when I want to return the 0 value of the alpha rgba.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To this you need to log all your drawings as a "shadow canvas". The most common way is to create shape objects and store them in for example an array:

- Draw the shape on canvas
- Log its type, position, dimension, colors and orientation and store as an object and push that object to the array

When you need to get an isolated shape or object as an image:

- Get mouse position (if you want to click on the object to select it)
- Iterate the array of objects to see which object is "hit"
- Create a temporary canvas of the dimension of that shape
- Draw in the shape into the temporary canvas
- Extract the data as an image (`ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h)` or `canvas.toDataURL()`)

When you need to resize your canvas you simply iterate all the objects and redraw them. You can even serialize your data for storage using this method.

An example of an object can be:

```
function Rectangle(x, y, w, h, fill, stroke) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.fill = fill;
    this.stroke = stroke;
}
```

You can extend this object to render it self to canvas as well as giving you a bitmap of itself isolated from the other shapes. Add this to the above code:

```
Rectangle.prototype.render = function(ctx) {
    if (this.fill) {                  /// fill only if fill is defined
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    if (this.stroke) {                /// stroke only if stroke is defined
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.toBitmap = function() {

    var tcanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),  /// create temp canvas
        tctx = tcanvas.getContext('2d');             /// temp context

    tcanvas.width = this.width;         /// set width = shape width
    tcanvas.height = this.height;
    tctx.translate(-this.x, -this.y);   /// make sure shape is drawn at origin

    this.render(tcxt);                  /// render itself to temp context

    return tcanvas.toDataURL();         /// return image (or use getImageData)
}
```

You simply draw your shapes, create the object based on the positions etc:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h, fillColor, strokeColor);

myShapeArray.push(rect);
```

When you need to render the shapes:

```
for(var i = 0, shape; shape = myShapeArray[i++];)
    shape.render(ctx);
```

And when you need to get its bitmap (you retrieved its index in advance with the mouse click):

```
var image = myShapeArray[index].toBitmap();
```

And of course: you can make similar objects for circles, lines etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Honestly curious, how well does this scale? The OP mentioned having to bring in 200 PNGs to his Canvas, would you recommend any way of doing so efficiently, or should 200 be easily accomplished with the same technique?

Comment: @mori57 this works pretty well with modern JS engines (in particular V8 but also others). This is easy to compile for the JS parser so the efficiency is pretty good.

Comment: This looks good, thanks! With this in mind I started building and came up with something else based upon what you are saying. I will mark your answer as the correct answer since it will be best for others. If possible after marking correct, I will post mine below so you can see what I came up with. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to know, @Ken! I've wondered about this ever since my first attempts trying out canvas... it's always nice to have more options! :)

Comment: @mori57 options are good :) Just to add: I used a similar approach for a [particle system (tutorial purpose)](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/12/part-1-lets-make-a-basic-particle-system-using-html5-only/) which can spawn thousands of similar objects but with additional complexity. A key thing to have in mind (especially in regards to V8) is to not add/change properties after the instance has been created or change "types" (JS is of course type-less, but the compiler appreciate consistency type-ish wise, ie. don't change number to string etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Canvas is a bitmap graphics tool. Anything you draw into a single context becomes part and parcel of the same object. You can't get separate image data for each "object" you used to draw on that canvas... it's painted ... flattened ... into those pixel positions for that bitmap as soon as you hit `draw()`.

The only way you could do something like what you are looking for would be to create separate canvas contexts that you overlay on top of each other. This would be better handled by utilizing a library such as KineticJS (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/). The only other option would be to use an object oriented drawing tool such as SVG, (through Raphael.js, for example: http://raphaeljs.com) which does preserve separate objects in the the graphics space.

For reference about getImageData, see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

Comment: Do you mean to place multiple contexts in the save canvas? getImageData seems to ignore that to, if I request the imagedata of my ctx context where nothing is drawn, it still goes down to my background context (other getContext('2d')) to return that data.

Comment: No, I mean you'd have to have separate canvas objects, each with their own context, and you'd have to layer them over each other with CSS or JS.

Comment: That is going to ask a lot of the browser when I place like 200 canvases on my page. I'll go and look if I can find something more usefull for my projects. But thanks, I now know that it's not possible the way I want it to.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't the answer you were looking for, but for that number of items, I'd highly recommend looking at Raphael or SVG in general. Vector graphics tend to be lighter weight, anyhow, though if you're importing a lot of PNGs like that, you're going to run into issues eventually, I think. There are several good libraries out there for both Canvas and SVG. Good luck, and if you find a solution, post it here so other can learn as well!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Raphael, that's a nice one! I will digg into it tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigonometry instead of trying to locate your colors with getImageData.

For example, if you have a circle defined like this:

```
var centerX=150;
var centerY=150;
var radius=20;
var circleColor="red";
```

Then you can test if any x,y is inside that circle like this:

```
// returns true if x,y is inside the red circle
isXYinCircle(140,140,centerX,centerY,radius);

function isXYinCircle(x,y,cx,cy,r){
    var dx=x-cx;
    var dy=y-cy;
    return(dx*dx+dy*dy<=r*r);
}
```

If the x,y is inside that red circle then you know the color at x,y is "red"

If you have multiple overlapping circles you can test each circle in increasing z-index order.  The last circle that reports x,y inside will be the color at x,y.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `that` is not a `CanvasGraphicsContext`. Try:

```
that.draw();
imgData = ctx.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1);
```

Comment: In fact, but it seems to be what he wants.

Comment: I understand that i need to draw the circle first, i do that later in my code, but what if i've got a background rect in the context, when I click next to the circle, it will get the imageData of the background rect, when I want to return the 0 value of the alpha rgba.

Comment: So you have to check whether the mouse pointer is exactly inside your circle (distance from pointer to circle center < circle radius).

Comment: And you'll have to store the coordinates and sizes of those circles in your array, and test that mouse pointer x/y against that array every time, because those objects do not exist as separate entities that can be queried/manipulated after they are drawn into the canvas context.

Comment: Still, that's not what I want, what if (that is becoming the case) I place a png image on the canvas. Little more difficult to calculate that shape.

Comment: It's the difference between putting a decal on your car vs spray-painting flames on the hood. In Canvas, when you say `draw()` you are spray-painting permanently into the "hood". You can't pick up objects from the canvas, as they now are all part of the same piece. You can draw more objects onto the hood, or even paint over objects that are there, but you're just changing pixel values in a bitmap, which have no intrinsic relationship to each other beside belonging to a parent map of color values. They don't have context to each other, and they do not have or react to events.

Comment: In the case of your PNG, you're basically copying its pixel data into the mapped positions of the Canvas context's map, as I understand it. This is all based on explorations I made when trying to do something similar, and was why I ended up going with SVG via Raphael.js as I needed objects I could interact with, with their own context and events.

Comment: If you must use Canvas, you might have to look into libraries like Kinetic.js. My guess is that underneath the hood, they are managing several image contexts, and layering them on top of each other for those instances when you want separate, manipulable elements (stated here, actually: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-layer-management-with-kineticjs/).

Answer (score 0):

At first, I create my 2 canvas elements. 1 to display, 1 to calculate the pixeldata.

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');

var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

c.width = ctx.width = c2.width = ctx2.width = width;
c.height = ctx.height = c2.height = ctx2.height = height;
```

Than I make my function to create an image

```
function Afbeelding(src, X, Y, W, H) {
    var that = this;
    that.X = X;
    that.Y = Y;
    that.W = W;
    that.H = H;
    that.onClick = function () { };
    that.image = new Image(that.W, that.H);
    that.image.src = src;
    that.draw = function (context) { 
        context = (typeof context != 'undefined') ? context : ctx;
        context.save();
        context.translate(that.X, that.Y);
        context.drawImage(that.image, 0, 0, that.W, that.H);
        context.restore();
    }
```

When a document.click event is fired, the next function (inside the Afbeelding function) will be called:

```
that.clicked = function (e) {
    if ((e.pageX > that.X - (that.W / 2) && e.pageX < that.X + (that.W / 2)) && (e.pageY > that.Y - (that.H / 2) && e.pageY < that.Y + (that.H / 2))) {
        if (that.isNotTransparent(e)) {
            that.onClick();
        }
    }
}
```

This function (also inside the Afbeelding function) is used to check the pixel for transparancy.

```
    that.isNotTransparent = function (e) {
        var result = false;
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        that.draw(ctx2);
        var imgData = ctx2.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1);
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        if (imgData.data[3] > 0) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And all below is to lauch the things up above.

```
var items = new Array();

var afb = new Afbeelding();
afb.draw();
afb.onClick = function () {
    alert('clicked');
}
items.push(afb);


document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        item.clicked(e);
    });
});
```